# How to fix memory bug in my c program?

Tags: c, memory-management

It was showing errors as Array size too large, Structure size too large, too much global data defined in a file. Please show me how to allocate dynamic memory?

```
struct
{
   doublereal a[25000000];

} _BLNK__;
static doublereal x[22500]  /* was [3][7500] */;

static doublereal vn[12], del, eul[22500]   /* was [3][1500] */;
```

Comment: though it is as easy as doing `something = malloc(N * sizeof(elements)); ... free(something);`, I suspect there must a better way, instead of doing such a memory hungry program...

Answer (score 2):

Allocate the data on the heap, rather than on the stack. Use pointers and allocate the memory in an initialization routine.

Also, do some calculations to work out if you have enough memory e.g. 25000000 * 16 bytes => 400MB of memory.  (no idea how big `doublereal` is).

Answer (score 0):

try dynamic memory allocation with malloc and pointer like:

```
typedef struct
{
   doublereal a[25000000];    
} _BLNK__;    
...
{    
_BLNK__ *mypointer = malloc(sizeof*mypointer);
mypointer->a[0] = 0;
mypointer->a[1] = 1;
...
free(mypointer);
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN_A (25000000)
struct
{
   doublereal* a;

}_BLNK__;

#define LEN_X (22500)
#define LEN_VN (12)
#define LEN_EUL (22500)


#define INIT_BLNK(x) x.a=(doublereal*)malloc(LEN_A*sizeof(doublereal))
#define FREE_BLNK(x) if(x.a!=0)free(x.a)

static doublereal *x;
static doublereal *vn,del,*eul;

int main()
{
   _BLNK__ Item;

   x = (doublereal*)malloc(LEN_X*sizeof(doublereal));
   vn = (doublereal*)malloc(LEN_VN*sizeof(doublereal));
   eul = (doublereal*)malloc(LEN_EUL*sizeof(doublereal));


   INIT_BLNK(Item);

   //Do whatever you wish


   //Return memory to the OS
   free(x);
   free(vn);
   free(eul);

   FREE_BLNK(Item);

   return 0;
}
```

Try using this. I just wrote the code here so if there are any compiler errors try to fix them

Comment: Please indent properly. This is especially important when giving example code as an answer! And you're not solving the real problem: This is just way, WAY too big of a 2D array.

Comment: Also, if statements cannot be placed inside of parenthesis. Why not use a function instead of a #define? Failing that, use the `do { ... } while(0)` pattern to make it a proper statement.

Comment: Yeah I should have made `FREE_BLNK(x) if(x.a!=0)free(x.a)` also `_BLNK__ Item` must be declared in the beginning since it's `C`. In my defense, like  I've said, it was written right here, didn't try to compile it, editing now. Calling a function is slower than using a macro to inline your code.

Comment: Actually, inline functions can be just as fast as macros, and they're a lot easier to write too :) Learn to embrace the `inline static`!

Comment: `inline static` is not guarantied by the compiler to be inline at least, as I recall, in vc++ documentation it states the fact somewhere ( I know I was disappointed too :p ), `__forceinline` supposedly is guarantied to be inline but I've also read somewhere that, during optimization it can also be made into a regular function call ( not stated in vc++ documentation). Disregarding the previous statement (as I use inline in c++ and the previous was only stated for fun) I didn't know that `C` had inline functions.

Comment: inline function in C are standardized as part of C99, I believe, so if you need to target really old compilers you might have to use macros, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

The statement

```
doublereal a[25000000];
```

allocates memory on the stack.  There is a strict limit on the size of the stack, and you can find it on a linux or osx system by running:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

which is 8192K = 8M.

You are trying to allocate `25000000 * 8 = 200000000` bytes `= 190 M` on a 32 bit system, which is much larger than the limit.

You have three choices:

1) reduce the size of the array

2) dynamically allocate memory (`doublereal *a = (doublereal *)malloc(sizeof(doublereal) * 25000000)`)

3) increase stack size (but this requires administrative privileges on all machines that this program will run on)

Comment: That is part of a struct definition and does not necessarily allocate on the stack

Comment: Also, increasing maximum stack size does not require administrative privileges on most machines. I can write a program to switch its stack over to a heap-allocated chunk on Linux easily enough, for example. And on debian linux, there is by default no hard limit on stack size (there is a soft limit that can be overridden by the user)

Comment: Given the error, the struct must have been allocated on the stack.  If it were heap-allocated, on most systems this would not cause the original problem.

Comment: doublereal has size 8 bytes on 32-bit platform.  An array of `25000000` doublereals has size `25000000 B *8 = 200000000 B ~ 195312 KB ~ 190M`

Comment: Whoops, read it wrong - kept thinking it was an array of _BLNK__ - still, though, this is not stack memory, as it is declared as `static`.

Comment: yes. As I've explained before, here and in other comments, the OP's declaration does not allocate any stack data at all; it's all static, global data. Talking about stack limits will only confuse him, when the compiler goes right out and says the problem is too much global data.